# "node.exe exited with code -1073741819" When building in VS2019

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2019

I have an asp .net core-project with react and typescript as front end.

I came back to work this morning, ran "Build" on my project, got this error message. Does anyone know what it means and how to fix it?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error MSB6006 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeJs\node.exe"
>   exited with code -1073741819. MyProject.Web   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\TypeScript\3.5\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets    463

The only hint I can see is File: "Typescript Targets"
When I checked Solution Properties->Typescript Builds I see that my selected Typescript version (3.1) is "unavailable" and that the only available version is 3.5, so I changed to 3.5, but that didnt do anything

Comment: Googled a bit just for fun and realized that -1073741819 = 0xFFC0000005, and if you strip away the 0xFF you end up with 0xC0000005, which is Windows' exception code for (memory) Access Violation. I don't know what could be causing it or how to fix it though. I suppose you're running VS as Administrator, and that you tried cleaning and rebuilding your solution?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help :) ...Yes, Im running VS as an admin.I have run clean and rebuild a few times

Comment: Having the same issue, just came up today randomly. Occurs on multiple separate solutions that we have. Unsure of solution at this time.

Comment: Found the problem: I had a `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable set on my computer that overrode the memory limit, which was causing an error when `node.exe` was invoked from Visual Studio. Absolutely untraceable, and lucky I remembered I had set the variable not too long ago. Removing the `NODE_OPTIONS` variable worked after restarting VS.

Answer (score 2):

Correct answer (for me):

Turns out Ive lost the NuGet-package Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild, I reinstalled it and now it works

Answer (score 0):

only way I have found to solve this is rebooting

Answer (score 0):

My trouble was the versions of node.js, I upgraded from 10 to 18 node version in my windows 10 and my Visual Studio 2019 has 12.2 version.

The node of Visual Studio 2019 is here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeJs>

For running other applications I had taht set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider and then 12.2 version of Visual Studio doesn't support this option.

I deleted this option of setting and it working.